# How to get a callback for every echo?

Tags: php, output-buffering

I wanted to use output buffering to make my logs prettier by processing any echos, but `ob_start` and `ob_implicit_flush` don't seem to work how I thought. Here's what I'm trying (this is a cli script):

```
<?php

ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 0);  
ini_set("implicit_flush", 1);

ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_start(function($s) {
    return "x $s\n";
});


echo 'derp';

echo 'flurp';

sleep(3);

ob_end_flush();
```

The output I want is

```
x derp
x flurp
```

But what I get instead is

```
x derpflurp
```

After 3 seconds. Is there any way to get a callback for each echo so that I can process the content and then output it immediately?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer is actually quite simple. Pass `1` as the 2nd argument to `ob_start` (in PHP 5.4+, `1` has a special meaning prior to that, so I guess use `2`):

```
<?php

ob_start(function($s) {
    if($s !== '') {
        return "x $s\n";
    }
},1);


echo 'derp';

echo 'flurp';

sleep(3);

ob_end_flush();
```

The `ob_implicit_flush` isn't needed and doesn't seem to do anything.

Although I get an extra `x` at the end of my output now (after the 3 seconds are up):

```
x derp
x flurp
x
```

I'm not sure what that's about. It's not there's any trailing spaces after `?>` because I didn't even put an end tag....

This can be fixed with an `if` condition:

```
ob_start(function($s) {
    if($s !== '') {
        return "x $s\n";
    }
},1);
```

Comment: There's probably an automatic flush of the output buffer at the end, even if the buffer is empty.

Comment: I guess so. Seems odd to invoke the callback with an empty string though.

Comment: Prior to PHP 5.4.0, the value 1 was a special case value that set the chunk size to 4096 bytes. This will only work if you know the chunk size, which could be difficult to determine.

Answer (score 0):

output_callback
... The function will be called when the output buffer is flushed (sent) or cleaned (with ob_flush(), ob_clean() or similar function) ...

so you only get the whole output after the end (end_flush() )

Comment: Yes, I was hoping the `ob_implicit_flush(true)` would have caused a flush after every echo like the descriptions says: "Implicit flushing will result in a flush operation after every output call, so that explicit calls to flush() will no longer be needed."

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired results by forcing a flush between calls

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_start(function($s) {
    return "x $s\n";
});

echo 'derp';
ob_get_contents();
ob_flush();
echo 'flurp';

sleep(3);

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Was hoping to avoid explicit flushes. I'd have just written a custom function forget about this ob non-sense if I wanted to flush every time :-)

Comment: I played around with a few ways but without that explicit flush it never worked.

Comment: You can't remove the `ob_flush()`?

Comment: There's a way. I found a solution. Look at my answer :-)